# web service webservicex.net for currency conversion in android

Tags: android, web-services, currency, ksoap

I'm trying to use [webservicex.net](http://www.webservicex.net/currencyconvertor.asmx?op=ConversionRate) in android for currency conversion using ksoap2.

However, it returns 0!!
It doesn't even throw any exception, just returns 0 even if I give wrong parameter, though it works just fine using provided webservice.

```
String NAME_SPACE = "http://www.webservicex.net/";
Static String URL = "http://www.webservicex.net/currencyconvertor.asmx";
Static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate";
Static String METHOD_NAME = "ConversionRate";

String webResult = null;

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Strings.NAME_SPACE, Strings.METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("FromCurrency", "USD");
request.addProperty("ToCurrency", "PKR");

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelop.dotNet = true;
envelop.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpRequest = new HttpTransportSE(Strings.URL);
androidHttpRequest.debug = true;
try {

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        androidHttpRequest.call(Strings.SOAP_ACTION, envelop);
        webResult = envelop.getResponse().toString();

        if (webResult != null)
            break;
        }

} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("APP", "ERROR: " + e.getMessage());   
}

return webResult;
```

Please correct me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: On SO, you are allowed to reply on your own thread with an answer if you've found the problem yourself. ;)

Comment: @ForceMagic I replied to my thread, i'll mark it as an answer but after 48 hours.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using wrong NAME_SPACE so it wasn't fetching expected result.

Little change worked for me.

```
String NAME_SPACE = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/";   // WORKS WITH THIS

String NAME_SPACE = "http://www.webservicex.net/";   // BRINGS 0
```